# Python text with nested brackets to nested list

Tags: python, parsing

I'd like to parse a text structured with nested brackets to a nested list (max depth 2).
Is there any module that fit to this job? The python standard lib. would be nice.

Thank you for all replies in advance.

Here`s the text:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code:

```
for i in range(len(txt)):
    if type(txt[i]) == list:
        for x in range(len(txt[i])):
            print(txt[i][x],end=" ")
        print("")
    else:
        print(txt[i])
```

Comment: The object "txt" is a string which means type(txt) == str is True. I think that capture would be confusing. Sorry for that

Comment: Oh right! I forgot I wasn't dealing with an actual list! Sorry for that.